# Leaflet.routing itinerary search: trying to allow the user to set the profile (car, foot...)

Tags: leaflet

Even though the CSS is not properly compatible (some bugs and stuff not showing properly), I'm trying to use Leaflet routing machine for Openroute service with a key. But I still need to figure out how to allow the user to change the driver's profile.

[image]

Files are:

[The leaflet routing machine by Gérald Niel](https://framagit.org/gegeweb/scasb-calcul-itineraires-velo) , and [the javascript is here](https://parcours.scasb.org/assets/libs/leaflet-routing-machine/leaflet-routing-machine.min.js)  and the css even if it's buggy [here](https://raw.githack.com/vincedchart/mappingforyou/main/leaflet-routing-machine.css)
and here for [Geocoder](https://mappingforyou.eu/javascript/Control.Geocoder.min.js)

The form to try to change the profile is:

[image]

```
    <form method="post">
    <label labelfor="aforma" id="aformb">Profile:</label>
    <select size="1" id="dropdown" name="dropdown" id="routeprofile" onchange="profileFunction(this)">
    <option value="driving-car">Car</option>
    <option value="driving-hgv">Truck</option>
    <option value="cycling-regular">Bike</option>
    <option value="cycling-road">Road bike</option>
    <option value="cycling-mountain">Mountain bike</option>
    <option value="cycling-electric">Electric bike</option>
    <option value="foot-walking">Walking</option>
    <option value="foot-hiking">Hiking</option>
    <option value="wheelchair">Wheelchair</option>
    </select>
    </form>
```

I'm giving a temporary default profile before the user chooses, give the api key, and once the user change profile, a console log is successfully triggered in the console by "*Value after trigger:cycling-electric*".

```
var ors_token = '7654567898765';
let routingprofile = 'driving-car';

function profileFunction() {
    routingprofile_getready = document.getElementById("dropdown");
};
```

Some values are entered there:

```
const osrRouter = L.routing.openroute(ors_token, {
        format: 'json',
        language: 'fr',
        "timeout": 30 * 1000, // 30"
        "retries": 2,
        "retryDelay": 1000,
        "retryOn": [],
            "profile": routingprofile,
        routingQueryParams: {
            "attributes": [
                "avgspeed",
                "percentage"
            ],
            "elevation": "true",
            "extra_info": [
                "waytype",
                "surface",
                "waycategory",
                "suitability",
                "steepness",
                "tollways",
                "traildifficulty",
                "osmid",
                "roadaccessrestrictions",
                "countryinfo"
            ],
            "id": "rounting_request",
            "instructions": "true",
            "instructions_format": "text",
            "language": "fr",
            "maneuvers": "true",
            "geometry": "true",
            "roundabout_exits": "true",
            "preference": "recommended"
        }
    });
```

But I don't see the route profile changing.

```
 L.Routing.control({
   
    router: osrRouter,
     position: 'topleft',
     profile: routingprofile,
     collapsible: true,
    geocoder: L.Control.Geocoder.nominatim({}) 

   
}).addTo(map);
```

I'm currently trying to use the ProfileFunction function to update the profile property deep inside the OSRrouter constant with

```
osrRouter['profile'] = routingprofile;
```

I read that someone was able to change another example of

```
var control = L.Routing.control({
  waypoints: [
    L.latLng(57.74, 11.94),
    L.latLng(57.6792, 11.949)
  ],
  routeWhileDragging: true,
  geocoder: L.Control.Geocoder.nominatim(),
  router: L.Routing.graphHopper('a585904f-5193-4605-bc3c-870c4f472177' , {
    urlParameters: {
        vehicle: 'car'
    }
  })
}).addTo(map);
```

with:

```
control.getRouter().options.urlParameters.vehicle = 'foot';
```

But no success so far.

Comment: Whenever you have a question about Leaflet and are using also other JS libraries, please always add info about libraries used, which means links to home pages of those libraries. Please edit your question and add missing info for `L.Routing.control`.

Comment: @TomazicM i updated the info with a page link to this javascript, I think it's the only one used .

Comment: Without your link there is no way (or a lot of research) to guess what you are using. Natural assumption would be you are using this one https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-routing-machine, but there are also several other candidates here https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#routing, so one would have to go through all of them and match APIs to try to guess which one you are using.

Comment: And please explain (in the body of the question) what do you mean by "Even though the CSS is not properly compatible".

Comment: @Tomazic sorry but there is two links inside my text referring to https://parcours.scasb.org/assets/libs/leaflet-routing-machine/leaflet-routing-machine.min.js from https://framagit.org/gegeweb/scasb-calcul-itineraires-velo

Comment: Yes, those links are now present, but were not before. My comment afterwards was intended to explain why such links are important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing to do was first to set a variable to L.Routing.control as in

```
 var control = L.Routing.control({
     router: osrRouter,
     position: 'topleft',
     profile: routingprofile,
     collapsible: true,
    geocoder: L.Control.Geocoder.nominatim({})     
}).addTo(map);
```

and then update the profileFunction which is triggered when clicking in the dropdown menu to change the profile:

```
function profileFunction() {
        routingprofile_getready = document.getElementById("dropdown");
routingprofile = routingprofile_getready.value;
L.extend(osrRouter.options, { profile: routingprofile});
    control.route();   
};
```

**L.extend....** changes the routing profile, and **control.route** redraws the itinerary if exists, according to the profile. Done!